# Python: Exception is gone after try/except block

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'm really sorry if I duplicated some thread, but I really couldn't find an answer.
So, I have this little piece of code:

```
exception = None
updated_at = None
test_str = "obviously wrong"

for datetime_format in ['%d-%b-%Y %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M']:
    try:
        updated_at = int(datetime.strptime(test_str, datetime_format).timestamp())
        break
    except Exception as exception:
        pass

if updated_at is None:
    raise exception
```

Basically I don't want to break the loop if the first date format is wrong, but I want to throw an exception later if I fail at parsing the date.
Initially I was thinking that code is ok, but after a test run I was kinda shocked when I received an error:

> Got exception local variable 'exception' referenced before assignment!

So it seems that this exception variable is somehow cleared and gone ?
I really don't understand what is going on here ?
I would be really grateful if someone could explain me what is happening here :)

Comment: You're `break`ing the loop the first time it succeeds with `strptime`, so if it *does* succeed, `exception` will have no value

Comment: @JRiggles but if it succeeds the if check shouldn't be raised, since updated_at won't be None ?

Comment: Ah true. It is a bit odd to see a `break` within a `try` statement however

Comment: Interesting to see that the "exception" that's declared in the first line not only doesn't get the raised exception it is even undefined after the except block: I get a 'cannot access local variable 'exception' where it is not associated with a value' when accessing exception after the for loop if the exception was raised. I did not expect that.

Comment: *break* breaks out of the *for* loop - **not** the try/except block. Are you saying that you only want to raise an exception if **both** attempts to parse the date fail?

Comment: @DarkKnight, yes you are right. I want to break the loop if date is correct on 1st try, no point of trying 2nd date format. I'm passing on exception when 1st attempt will throw ValueError.

Answer (score 3):

That's because for some specific reasons `except ... as e` does not store `e` outside of `except` block:

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    ...

print(e)  # NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

You should assign `exception` explicitly:

```
exception = None
updated_at = None
test_str = "obviously wrong"

for datetime_format in ['%d-%b-%Y %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M']:
    try:
        updated_at = int(datetime.strptime(test_str, datetime_format).timestamp())
        break
    except Exception as e:
        exception = e

if updated_at is None:
    raise exception
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just learned something new today!

Comment: Do you know why `pdb` is unable to see `e` if execution stops within the `except` block? E.g. if I put a breakpoint just after the `except` clause. The workaround I've been using is to assign it to a variable, as you show here, but I'd quite like to know why because the current execution point is still within the block. It behaves as if `e` isn't actually a variable.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you only want to raise an exception if **both** attempts to parse the string fail. If that's the case then:

```
from datetime import datetime

test_str = "obviously wrong"

for datetime_format in ['%d-%b-%Y %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M']:
    try:
        updated_at = int(datetime.strptime(test_str, datetime_format).timestamp())
        break
    except Exception as exception:
        e = exception
else:
    raise e
```